# phonegap html/css/js app: how to display a slideshow at first run and not at subsequent run

Tags: cordova, local-storage, single-page-application, phonegap-build

how to detect the first run (first run ever) of an HTML/CSS/JS app to display a swype slideshow to explain how it works?
The app is an Single Page App and I use phonegap build to compile.

thanks

Comment: First run ever? Or just during the current session?

Comment: yes first run ever by the user, when he just installed the app on his phone.

Comment: why did I get 2 votes down?

Comment: please someone help ?

Comment: Here's an answer and 1 upvote because this is not a bed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much you can do here, at least perfect solution don't exist here.

Basically what you need is a way to permanently store a flag somewhere on a mobile phone.

Only thing that will work here is a [**localStorage**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/). That information will stay there until phone is reseted or **`localStorage`** is manually cleaned (low probability).

Or you can use [**persistence.js**](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs) and store that flag into a local HTML5 webSQL database.
This solution will work only on a **`webkit`** browsers so **`localstorage`** is still your best choice. Fortunately this covers iOS and Android and it can be used on a Ripple emulator (if you use it to test your app on a desktop computer).

In the end you can also use cookies but this is such a fragile solution that I am advising you against it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precise answer. I am going to use `localstorage`.